# How to load nested array of xml in ssis using deserialization

Tags: c#, ssis

i am a new user of ssis.
Using deserialization,I want to know how to load into buffer all element of type parameter name.....item.
Thanks to help me.

This is the xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<parameter>
   <name>max_amount</name>
   <label>Max Amount</label>
   <unit>Millions</unit>
   <component>
       <type>Combo</type>
       <attributes>
         <type>Integer</type>
         <displayed>4</displayed>
         <selected>0</selected>
         <items>
           <item>5</item>
           <item>10</item>
           <item>20</item>
           <item>50</item>
         </items>
      </attributes>
    </component >
</parameter>
<parameter>
    <name>max_amount_again</name>
    <label>Max Amount_again</label>
    <unit>Millions_again</unit>
    <component>
      <type>Combo</type>
      <attributes>
          <type>Integer</type>
          <displayed>41</displayed>
          <selected>01</selected>
          <items>
            <item>50</item>
            <item>100</item>
            <item>200</item>
            <item>500</item>
          </items>
     </attributes>
    </component >
</parameter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried Data Flow, and in the Data Flow, use XML source and Merge Join to merge make the output like SQL table. Basically, how many levels of the XML, how many Merge Join you will be needed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.but i want to use Script component to achieve this , using deserialization. Thanks